# Edit button is undefined id of table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for an edit button:

```
<form method="post" action="pengiriman-input.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_transaksi']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Kirim" />
</form>
```

and in `pengiriman-input.php`

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['id_transaksi'] = $_POST['idtransaksi']; ?>
```

but the result is:

> **Undefined index:** idtransaksi in > C:\xampp\htdocs\delivery\pengiriman-input.php

How do I call the value of `$row['idtransaksi']` for `pengiriman-input.php`?

`$row['idtransaksi']` is from MySQL query.

Comment: Undefined index means that the key `idtransaksi` doesn't exist in the POST array. Try wrapping it in [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: Your form input has name `id` but you're querying `idtransaksi` on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo within post `name` as within your `name` attribute its `name='id'` and not `idtransaksi`

```
$_SESSION['id_transaksi'] = $_POST['idtransaksi'];
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It should be

```
$_SESSION['id_transaksi'] = $_POST['id'];
                                    ^^^
```

or you can check it either as using [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function of PHP

```
$_SESSION['id_transaksi'] = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$_SESSION['id_transaksi'] = $_POST['id'];
```

Because the name of your passed on hidden field is `id` and not `id_transaksi`.